# Magento related products sort order not working

Tags: sorting, related-products, sort

For some reason the sort order for related products is not working.

How can I sort the order asc to desc (low to high)?

Here is my current `/catalog/product/list/related.phtml` file:

```
<div class="block-content">
    <ul class="gerelateerde-producten-list" id="block-related">
    <?php $i = 0; foreach ($this->getItems() as $_item) : if($i < 2) {?>
        <li class="item">
            <div class="product">
                <div class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'thumbnail')->resize(150, 170) ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>" /></div>
                <div class="product-details">
                    <p class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?></a></p>
                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true, '-related') ?>
                    <?php if(!$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()): ?>
                    <div class="related-box-check">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox related-checkbox" id="related-checkbox<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" name="related_products[]" value="<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" />
                        <label class="label-related" for="related-checkbox<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>"><span class="icon-related-product"></span>order</label>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php } $i++; endforeach ?>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('block-related', 'none-recursive')</script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="block-content">
<ul class="gerelateerde-producten-list" id="block-related">

<?php 
if (count($this->getItems())): 
$datarev = array();
foreach ($this->getItems() as $_item): 
  $datarev [] = $_item;  
endforeach; 

$datarev = array_reverse($datarev);
$i = 0;
foreach($datarev as $_item): ?>
    <li class="item">
        <div class="product">
            <div class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'thumbnail')->resize(150, 170) ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>" /></div>
            <div class="product-details">
                <p class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?></a></p>
                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true, '-related') ?>
                <?php if(!$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable()): ?>
                <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()): ?>
                <div class="related-box-check">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox related-checkbox" id="related-checkbox<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" name="related_products[]" value="<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" />
                    <label class="label-related" for="related-checkbox<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>"><span class="icon-related-product"></span>order</label>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
<?php 
$i++;
if ($i == 2) break;
endforeach;?>
<?php endif; ?>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">decorateList('block-related', 'none-recursive')</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works almost perfect, but I want to display only the first two items. So how can I change that? Therefore I used `<?php $i = 0; foreach ($this->getItems() as $_item) : if($i < 2) {?>`.

Comment: Are you check this code?